# Change value of cell via separate class

Tags: c#, excel

I have an Excel workbook with multiple sheets and a C# class that controls what is filled into each sheet's cells.  However, I cannot for the life of me figure out how to correctly populate the cells.

The class has a function called `BuildSheet` that tries to reference the sheet called `Rate_Lock`.

Here's my code:

```
public static void BuildSheet(Excel._Worksheet sheet, string transaction, string occ)
{
    Excel.Application objAppl;
    Excel._Workbook objWorkbook;
    Excel._Worksheet objLockSheet;

    try
    {
        objAppl = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject(
            "Excel.Application") as Excel.Application;
    }
    catch (System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException)
    {
        objAppl = new Excel.Application();
    }

    objWorkbook = (Excel._Workbook)objAppl.ActiveWorkbook;
    objLockSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)objAppl.Worksheets["Rate_Lock"];

    objLockSheet.Cells[18, 6] = transaction;
    objLockSheet.Cells[20, 6] = occ;
}
```

I wonder if I'm trying to reference the sheet incorrectly.  What's really weird about this is that the cells don't populate during debugging; however, once I stop debugging the cells are populated in Visual Studio.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT:  I should also mention that I'm receiving no errors.  Also, I've gotten this code to work in the code behind specific sheets using the following:

```
objSheet = (Excel._Worksheet)this.Application.Worksheets["Rate_Lock"];
```

The "this" keyword doesn't work when trying to refer to a separate sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Well, normally you should use the `Value` property of the cell to input text. (Or `Value2` or `Text`).

So:

```
((Range)objLockSheet.Cells[18, 6]).Value = transaction;
((Range)objLockSheet.Cells[20, 6]).Value = occ;
```

Comment: Thanks, Daniel.  I did try that as well as:

objLockSheet.Cells[18, 6].Value = transaction;

For whatever reason, neither are working.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the `Cells` return an object, so you need to cast it to a `Range` before using the value. Did you chek if `Application.ScreenUpdating` is set to true???

Comment: When I work with excel interop, I always use `Workbook` and `Worksheet`. I never used `_Workbook` and `_Worksheet`. I don't know if it has something to do with it.

Comment: Another thing: the `sheet` parameter you pass to the method is never being used by your code. You are applying changes to the `Rate_Lock` sheet only.

Comment: Yeah, the `sheet` parameter will be used later -- it's not being used yet.

I tried removing the underscores but alas, still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround solution.  Not clean, but it works.  I had to declare the sheet as an object in the opening sheet's underlying class, and then pass it to this class.  Trying to declare a sheet in an external class simply wouldn't work.